# How to use this library to show a PDF when this screen is opened in Flutter

Tags: android, pdf, dart, flutter

I have a pdf_screen.dart file that will show a PDF directly when opened, does anyone can explain me how to use the functions of this library called flutter pdf viewer just to show my pdf?

[Flutter PDF Viewer Library Example](https://github.com/pycampers/flutter_pdf_viewer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

```
    class _PdfScreenState extends State<PdfScreen> {

      final DocumentSnapshot document;
      String path;
      var dir;

      _PdfScreenState(this.document);


      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getPdf();
      }

      Future<void> getPdf() async {
        try {
          dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          setState(() {
            path = "${dir.path}/${document["title"]}.pdf";
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        if (path == null) {


   print("loading");
      return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {

      return Container(
             child: ??; // I need to show my PDF here, I need to pass the path 
                       // variable but PdfViewer is a function and it doesn't 
                       // return a widget, how to implement?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the readme says, this library launches a new intent, so it replaces your Flutter app in the stack until you use the back button. The example is clear how to achieve this.

However, as the readme continues, a proof-of-concept is available allowing you to render the PDF inside your Flutter app. Check out the branch from github to explore more.

> A proof of concept for inline PDFs is available at the *inline* branch.

Comment: I don't understand where to call PdfViewer.load...without an onpressed:, my screen will open and need to show the pdf directly.

Comment: At the end of `getPdf` looks likely. Alternatively do it instead of navigating to this page.